# Modelling of a heat exchanger

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-equations, models, thermal-conduction

re mathematician so im so lost... Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that you can't start from physical principles and get the equation you wrote in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split quite a long answer into paragraphs.

**Introduction.** The equation in your answer could be seen as an equation of internal energy of a fluid, with the internal energy proportional to temperature, $e = c \,T$, in a "mixed-integral/differential form", since you're integrating over a section of the pipe (and implicitly assuming uniform physical quantities over each section) while you keep the dependence on the axial coordinate $z$.

**Principles.** Internal energy equation is not a "fundamental principle", but it could be derived combining:

- the **$1^{st}$ principle of thermodynamics**, that for a closed system reads
  \begin{equation}
  \dot{E}^{tot} = P^{ext} + \dot{Q}^{ext}
  \end{equation}
- the **theorem of kinetic energy**, derived itself by the **$2^{nd}$ principle of dynamics** if you need to start from a principle. The theorem of kinetic energy for a closed system reads
  \begin{equation}
    \dot{K} = P^{ext} + P^{int} \ .
  \end{equation}
  It's possible to define the internal energy as the difference $E = E^{tot} - K$ of the total energy $E^{tot}$ and the "macroscopic" kinetic energy $K$, and thus obtaining the equation for the internal energy of a closed system
  \begin{equation}
  \dot{E} = \dot{Q}^{ext} - P^{int} \ .
  \end{equation}

**Principles in differential form.** If you write these equations for a fluid in differential form, you get

- balance of total energy
  \begin{equation}
    \rho \dfrac{D e^{tot}}{Dt} = \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} + \nabla \cdot \left( \mathbb{T} \cdot \mathbf{u} \right) - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q} 
  \end{equation}
- balance of momentum and kinetic energy
  \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
    \rho \dfrac{D \mathbf{u}}{Dt} & = \rho \mathbf{g} + \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} \\
    \rho \dfrac{D}{Dt}\dfrac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2} & = \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} + \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} \cdot \mathbf{u} \ ,
  \end{aligned}\end{equation}
  and the equation of internal energy reads
  \begin{equation}
    \rho \dfrac{D e}{Dt} = - \mathbb{T} : \nabla \mathbf{u} - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q} \ .
  \end{equation}

**The equation for temperature you need.** Now, we'll take this last equation, with the assumption of uniform velocity $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{v} = v \mathbf{\hat{z}}$, aligned with the axis of the pipe (assuming a pipe with constant section), so that $\mathbb{T} : \nabla \mathbf{u} = 0$. Writing the material derivative explicitly using partial derivatives in space and times, and using $e = c \, T$ with constant and uniform $c$
\begin{equation}
  \frac{D e}{D t} = \frac{\partial e}{\partial t} + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla e
 = \partial_t e + v \partial_z e
 = c \left( \partial_t T + v \partial_z e T \right) \ .
\end{equation}

We're almost there. Following all the assumptions we made so far, we go the equation
\begin{equation}
  \rho c \left( \partial_t T + v \partial_z T \right) = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q} \ .
\end{equation}
Let's integrate this equation over a section of the pipe,
\begin{equation}
  \int_A \rho c \left( \partial_t T + v \partial_z T \right) = - \int_A \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q} = - \int_{\partial A} q_n - \int_A \partial_z q_z \ ,
\end{equation}
having used the divergence theorem to separate the heat flux exchanged with the outside, and the heat flux exchanged between neighboring sections of the fluids flowing in the pipe (by diffusion, if we use Fourier model $q_z = -K \partial_z T$; this term is not there in your equation). The last things we need to do are:

- add the model of the heat conduction through the walls of the pipe
  \begin{equation}
    q_n = U (T - T_{M})
  \end{equation}
- evaluate the integrals:
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \int_A \rho c \left( \partial_t T + v \partial_z T \right) & = \rho c \pi R^2 \left( \partial_t T + v \partial_z T \right) \\
    - \int_{\partial A} q_n & = - 2 \pi R U (T-T_M) \\
   - \int_A \partial_z q_z & = \int_A k \partial_{zz} T = \pi R^2 \partial_{zz} T \ ,
  \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
- and put everything together, doing the required algebra
  \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
    \partial_t T + v \partial_z T & = - \dfrac{2 \pi R}{\pi R^2 \rho c} U (T-T_M) + \frac{K}{\rho c} \partial_{zz} T = \\
  & = - \dfrac{2 U}{R \rho c} (T-T_M) + \frac{K}{\rho c}\partial_{zz} T  \ ,
  \end{aligned}\end{equation}
  that should be exactly what you need with the definition of $C = \rho c$ as the coefficient per unit volume, and the extra diffusion term within the fluid flowing inside the pipe.

**EDIT: non-dimensional analysis.** Let's perform non-dimensional analysis to make non-dimensional numbers appear and compare the influence of the physical processes involved in the problem.

\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{\overline{T}}{\overline{t}} \partial_{\tilde{t}} \tilde{T} +   \dfrac{\overline{T}\overline{v}}{\overline{L}} \partial_{\tilde{z}} \tilde{T} = 
- \dfrac{2 \overline{U}}{\overline{R} \overline{C}} \overline{\Delta T} (T-T_M) + \dfrac{\overline{K}\overline{T}}{\overline{C}\overline{L}^2} \partial_{\tilde{z}\tilde{z}} \tilde{T}
\end{equation}
and dividing by $\frac{\overline{T}}{\overline{t}}$,
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\tilde{t}} \tilde{T} + \dfrac{\overline{t}\overline{v}}{\overline{L}} \partial_{\tilde{z}} \tilde{T} = 
- \dfrac{2 \overline{U} \overline{t}}{\overline{R} \overline{C}} \dfrac{\overline{\Delta T}}{\overline{T}} (\tilde{T}-\tilde{T}_M) + \dfrac{\overline{K}\overline{t}}{\overline{C}\overline{L}^2} \partial_{\tilde{z}\tilde{z}} \tilde{T}
\end{equation}

Now, if the problem have no independent time and length scales $\overline{t}$ and $\overline{L}$, you could set
\begin{equation}
  \overline{v} = \frac{\overline{L}}{\overline{t}} \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \overline{t} = \frac{\overline{L}}{\overline{v}} \ ,
\end{equation}

so that the equation becomes

\begin{equation}
\partial_{\tilde{t}} \tilde{T} + \partial_{\tilde{z}} \tilde{T} = 
- \dfrac{2 \overline{U} \overline{L}}{\overline{v}\overline{R} \overline{C}} \dfrac{\overline{\Delta T}}{\overline{T}} (\tilde{T}-\tilde{T}_M) + \dfrac{\overline{K}\overline{L}}{\overline{v}\overline{C}\overline{L}^2} \partial_{\tilde{z}\tilde{z}} \tilde{T} \ ,
\end{equation}

Roughly speaking, if you compare the values of the 2 adimenional numbers (and thus you can compare them without any problem), if one of the two numbers if much bigger than the other you can neglect the other term. Namely if their ratio is

\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{\overline{U} \overline{L}}{\overline{K}} \dfrac{\overline{L}}{\overline{R}}\dfrac{\overline{\Delta T}}{\overline{T}} >> 1 \ ,
\end{equation}

I think it's safe to neglect the diffusion term, since it's negligible if compared with the heat exchange with the external system.

Comment: That's an amazing answer but what happends with the term with $\partial_{zz}T$? It doens not appear in the answer provided

Comment: This term represents temperature diffusion in the fluid. I guess that it's usually negligible, but you could easily check with a non-dimensional analysis. I'll add it at the end of the answer

Comment: Okay perfect. Thank u very much!!! One laste question, what represents $\mathbb{T}$

Comment: $\mathbb{T}$ is the stress tensor, that can be usually written as the sum of pressure and viscous contributions. The model of a Newtonian fluid (that can be used in many cases of interest of real life/engineering) reads $\mathbb{T} = - p \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{S}$, and where you can write the viscous stress tensor as a linear function of the space derivative of the velocity field $\mathbb{S} = \mu \left[ \nabla \mathbf{u} + \nabla^T \mathbf{u} \right] + \lambda (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) \mathbb{I}$

Comment: The last expression of the viscous stress tensor comes from isotropy.